# Mostrar mensaje de acuerdo a complejidad de contraseña

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy en la realización de un pequeño Password Checker para saber que tan compleja es mi contraseña, quisiera que al momento de digitar la contraseña y al mostrar el nivel en que se encuentra muestre su respectivo mensaje. Estos son los lineamientos a tener en cuenta para mostrar el mensaje:

- Cuando el nivel de complejidad de la contraseña muestre **Your password is too week** mostrar el mensaje que se encuentra en el recuadro rojo.
- Cuando el nivel de complejidad de la contraseña muestre **Your password is medium** mostrar el mensaje que se encuentra en el recuadro amarillo.
- Cuando el nivel de complejidad de la contraseña muestre **Your password is strong** mostrar el mensaje que se encuentra en el recuadro verde.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
html,body{
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  place-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
.container{
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  width: 900px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.container header{
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 33px;
}
.container form{
  margin: 20px 5px 10px 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.container form .field{
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
form .field input{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding-left: 15px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 17px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
form .field input:focus{
  border-color: #27ae60;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #2fd072;
}
form .field .showBtn{
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  user-select: none;
}
form .indicator{
  height: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: none;
}
form .indicator span{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgrey;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
form .indicator span:nth-child(2){
  margin: 0 3px;
}
form .indicator span.active:before{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.indicator span.weak:before{
  background-color: #ff4757;
}
.indicator span.medium:before{
  background-color: orange;
}
.indicator span.strong:before{
  background-color: #23ad5c;
}
form .text{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}
form .text.weak{
  color: #ff4757;
}
form .text.medium{
  color: orange;
}
form .text.strong{
  color: #23ad5c;
}


/*--------------------------------------------*/
.bad-score {
    border: #F17179 3px solid;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 0%);
}

.bad-score, .middle-score, .good-score {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: none;
}

.description-block {
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 30px rgb(0 0 0 / 7%);
    line-break: normal;
}

h2 img {
    margin-top: -7px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
}

.description-block > ul > li {
    background-image: url(images/bullet.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-y: 16px;
    padding-left: 17px;
}

.description-block ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: #59595C;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-family: KasperskyLight, Arial;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.description-block ul.score-description {
    list-style-position: inside;
}

.description-block ul.score-description li {
    background-image: url(images/list-type-triangle.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-y: 6px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.description-block h2 {
    margin: 35px 10px 35px 10px;
}

h2 {
    margin: 35px 0 35px -60px;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #59595C;
    font-family: KasperskyRegular, Arial;
}

.middle-score {
    border: #FFCB4D 3px solid;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 0%);
}

.good-score {
    border: #02A88E 3px solid;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 0%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Created By CodingNepal -->
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Password Strength Indicator | CodingNepal</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   </head>
   <body>
       <div class="container-fluid p-0">
           <div class="row no-gutters pt-3 pb-lg-5 pb-3 px-3 m-auto header">
               <div class="col-lg-9 col-6">
                   
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
      <div class="container">
         <header>Password Strength Indicator <br>in HTML CSS & JavaScript</header>
         <form action="#">
            <div class="field">
               <input onkeyup="trigger()" type="password" placeholder="Comprueba tu contraseña">
               <span class="showBtn">SHOW</span>
            </div>
            <div class="indicator">
               <span class="weak"></span>
               <span class="medium"></span>
               <span class="strong"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="text"></div>
         </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 pt-5 mb-5">
        <div class="description-block good-score mt-lg-5 pb-2" style="display: grid;">
            <h2>
                <img src="images/good.png">
                "¡Buena contraseña!"
            </h2>
            <ul>
               <li class="pb-4">
                   Tu contraseña es resistente al pirateo.
               </li> 
            </ul>
        </div>

          <div class="description-block middle-score mt-lg-5 pb-2" style="display: grid;">
            <h2>
                <img src="images/middle.png">
                "¡Es hora de cambiar la contraseña!" 
            </h2>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Tu contraseña se puede crackear fácilmente.
                </li>
                <ul class="score-description pb-4">
                    <li>La contraseña es común o es una palabra</li>
                </ul>
            </ul>        
        </div>


        <div class="description-block bad-score mt-lg-5 pb-2" style="display: grid;">
            <h2>
                <img src="images/bad.png">
                "!Hace tiempo que deberías haber cambiado la contraseña!"
            </h2>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Malas noticias
                </li>
                <ul class="score-description pb-4">
                    <li>La contraseña es demasiado corta</li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>


      <script>
         const indicator = document.querySelector(".indicator");
         const input = document.querySelector("input");
         const weak = document.querySelector(".weak");
         const medium = document.querySelector(".medium");
         const strong = document.querySelector(".strong");
         const text = document.querySelector(".text");
         const showBtn = document.querySelector(".showBtn");
         let regExpWeak = /[a-z]/;
         let regExpMedium = /\d+/;
         let regExpStrong = /.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,(,)]/;
         function trigger(){
           if(input.value != ""){
             indicator.style.display = "block";
             indicator.style.display = "flex";
             if(input.value.length <= 3 && (input.value.match(regExpWeak) || input.value.match(regExpMedium) || input.value.match(regExpStrong)))no=1;
             if(input.value.length >= 6 && ((input.value.match(regExpWeak) && input.value.match(regExpMedium)) || (input.value.match(regExpMedium) && input.value.match(regExpStrong)) || (input.value.match(regExpWeak) && input.value.match(regExpStrong))))no=2;
             if(input.value.length >= 6 && input.value.match(regExpWeak) && input.value.match(regExpMedium) && input.value.match(regExpStrong))no=3;
             if(no==1){
               weak.classList.add("active");
               text.style.display = "block";
               text.textContent = "Your password is too week";
               text.classList.add("weak");
             }
             if(no==2){
               medium.classList.add("active");
               text.textContent = "Your password is medium";
               text.classList.add("medium");
             }else{
               medium.classList.remove("active");
               text.classList.remove("medium");
             }
             if(no==3){
               weak.classList.add("active");
               medium.classList.add("active");
               strong.classList.add("active");
               text.textContent = "Your password is strong";
               text.classList.add("strong");
             }else{
               strong.classList.remove("active");
               text.classList.remove("strong");
             }
             showBtn.style.display = "block";
             showBtn.onclick = function(){
               if(input.type == "password"){
                 input.type = "text";
                 showBtn.textContent = "HIDE";
                 showBtn.style.color = "#23ad5c";
               }else{
                 input.type = "password";
                 showBtn.textContent = "SHOW";
                 showBtn.style.color = "#000";
               }
             }
           }else{
             indicator.style.display = "none";
             text.style.display = "none";
             showBtn.style.display = "none";
           }
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

De momento se muestran todos los mensajes pero desconozco como manipularlo para que se muestren de acuerdo al nivel de complejidad.

Comment: qué aportan tus `css` a la respuesta?

Comment: a que te refieres con "manipularlo"?

Comment: @L.Ronquillo Me refiero con "manipularlo" es como controlar para que se muestre el recuadro de acuerdo al nivel de complejidad que se va a mostrar al digitar la contraseña.

Comment: pero entiendo con tu pregunta que eso ya lo hace, no?

Comment: @L.Ronquillo Si te fijas en el fiddle esta mostrando todos los mensajes de entrada, quisiera que solo se muestre el mensaje indicado para cada nivel de complejidad de acuerdo a los lineamientos que agregue en mi pregunta inicial.

Comment: correcto, mi error, déjame lo veo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT***

Se añade el código que evita que se quede el recuadro si el `input` está vacío.

Agregue unas cosas para que tu programa funcione como deseas.

Primero, les di un ID a cada `<div>` que creaste, y les cambié su display a none, ya que, en principio, no debe mostrar ninguno. queda así:

```
<div class="description-block good-score mt-lg-5 pb-2" style="display: none;" id="good-score">
            <h2>
                <img src="images/good.png">
                "¡Buena contraseña!"
            </h2>
            <ul>
               <li class="pb-4">
                   Tu contraseña es resistente al pirateo.
               </li> 
            </ul>
        </div>

          <div class="description-block middle-score mt-lg-5 pb-2" style="display: none;" id="middle-score">
            <h2>
                <img src="images/middle.png">
                "¡Es hora de cambiar la contraseña!" 
            </h2>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Tu contraseña se puede crackear fácilmente.
                </li>
                <ul class="score-description pb-4">
                    <li>La contraseña es común o es una palabra</li>
                </ul>
            </ul>        
        </div>


        <div class="description-block bad-score mt-lg-5 pb-2" style="display: none;" id="bad-score">
            <h2>
                <img src="images/bad.png">
                "!Hace tiempo que deberías haber cambiado la contraseña!"
            </h2>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Malas noticias
                </li>
                <ul class="score-description pb-4">
                    <li>La contraseña es demasiado corta</li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**EDIT**

Se agrega un método que hace `display="none"` a los tres `<div>`

```
function ocultarDiv() {
        goodDiv.style.display = "none";
        middleDiv.style.display = "none";
        badDiv.style.display = "none";
    }
```

Segundo, teniendo esos datos, creé un método que activa y desactiva esos `<div>` en base a la fortaleza de la contraseña:

```
function activarDiv(ActiveDiv) {
            if (ActiveDiv.style.display == "grid") {
                return;
            } else {
                //primero, ocultamos todos los divs
                ocultarDiv();
                //después, activamos el que se mandó
                ActiveDiv.style.display = "grid";
            }

        }
```

`ActiveDiv` es una de las tres constantes que creamos al principio, pasamos una de esas tres como parámetro en este método. Si el parámetro que pasamos es el que está activo actualmente no hace nada, si no, desactiva el activo y activa el nuevo.

Ahora, teniendo el método listo, lo integramos en la función originar `Trigger()`, cuando activa uno de esos métodos, o cuando el `input` regresa a su estado vacío:

```
function trigger() {
        if (input.value != "") {
            indicator.style.display = "block";
            indicator.style.display = "flex";
            if (input.value.length <= 3 && (input.value.match(regExpWeak) || input.value.match(regExpMedium) || input.value.match(regExpStrong))) no = 1;
            if (input.value.length >= 6 && ((input.value.match(regExpWeak) && input.value.match(regExpMedium)) || (input.value.match(regExpMedium) && input.value.match(regExpStrong)) || (input.value.match(regExpWeak) && input.value.match(regExpStrong)))) no = 2;
            if (input.value.length >= 6 && input.value.match(regExpWeak) && input.value.match(regExpMedium) && input.value.match(regExpStrong)) no = 3;
            if (no == 1) {
                weak.classList.add("active");
                text.style.display = "block";
                text.textContent = "Your password is too week";
                text.classList.add("weak");
                activarDiv(badDiv);
            }
            if (no == 2) {
                medium.classList.add("active");
                text.textContent = "Your password is medium";
                text.classList.add("medium");
                activarDiv(middleDiv);
            } else {
                medium.classList.remove("active");
                text.classList.remove("medium");
            }
            if (no == 3) {
                weak.classList.add("active");
                medium.classList.add("active");
                strong.classList.add("active");
                text.textContent = "Your password is strong";
                text.classList.add("strong");
                activarDiv(goodDiv);
            } else {
                strong.classList.remove("active");
                text.classList.remove("strong");
            }
            showBtn.style.display = "block";
            showBtn.onclick = function () {
                if (input.type == "password") {
                    input.type = "text";
                    showBtn.textContent = "HIDE";
                    showBtn.style.color = "#23ad5c";
                } else {
                    input.type = "password";
                    showBtn.textContent = "SHOW";
                    showBtn.style.color = "#000";
                }
            }
        } else {
            indicator.style.display = "none";
            text.style.display = "none";
            showBtn.style.display = "none";
            ocultarDiv();
        }
    }
```

Con eso, probé y el código funciona correctamente. El código completo te lo dejo aquí debajo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Created By CodingNepal -->
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Password Strength Indicator | CodingNepal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
        <div class="row no-gutters pt-3 pb-lg-5 pb-3 px-3 m-auto header">
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-6">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <header>Password Strength Indicator <br>in HTML CSS & JavaScript</header>
        <form action="#">
            <div class="field">
                <input onkeyup="trigger()" type="password" placeholder="Comprueba tu contraseña">
                <span class="showBtn">SHOW</span>
            </div>
            <div class="indicator">
                <span class="weak"></span>
                <span class="medium"></span>
                <span class="strong"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="text"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 pt-5 mb-5">
        <div class="description-block good-score mt-lg-5 pb-2" style="display: none;" id="good-score">
            <h2>
                <img src="images/good.png">
                "¡Buena contraseña!"
            </h2>
            <ul>
                <li class="pb-4">
                    Tu contraseña es resistente al pirateo.
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="description-block middle-score mt-lg-5 pb-2" style="display: none;" id="middle-score">
            <h2>
                <img src="images/middle.png">
                "¡Es hora de cambiar la contraseña!"
            </h2>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Tu contraseña se puede crackear fácilmente.
                </li>
                <ul class="score-description pb-4">
                    <li>La contraseña es común o es una palabra</li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>


        <div class="description-block bad-score mt-lg-5 pb-2" style="display: none;" id="bad-score">
            <h2>
                <img src="images/bad.png">
                "!Hace tiempo que deberías haber cambiado la contraseña!"
            </h2>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Malas noticias
                </li>
                <ul class="score-description pb-4">
                    <li>La contraseña es demasiado corta</li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
        const indicator = document.querySelector(".indicator");
        const input = document.querySelector("input");
        const weak = document.querySelector(".weak");
        const medium = document.querySelector(".medium");
        const strong = document.querySelector(".strong");
        const text = document.querySelector(".text");
        const showBtn = document.querySelector(".showBtn");
        //agregamos los divs
        const goodDiv = document.getElementById("good-score");
        const middleDiv = document.getElementById("middle-score");
        const badDiv = document.getElementById("bad-score");
        let regExpWeak = /[a-z]/;
        let regExpMedium = /\d+/;
        let regExpStrong = /.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,-,(,)]/;
        function trigger() {
            if (input.value != "") {
                indicator.style.display = "block";
                indicator.style.display = "flex";
                if (input.value.length <= 3 && (input.value.match(regExpWeak) || input.value.match(regExpMedium) || input.value.match(regExpStrong))) no = 1;
                if (input.value.length >= 6 && ((input.value.match(regExpWeak) && input.value.match(regExpMedium)) || (input.value.match(regExpMedium) && input.value.match(regExpStrong)) || (input.value.match(regExpWeak) && input.value.match(regExpStrong)))) no = 2;
                if (input.value.length >= 6 && input.value.match(regExpWeak) && input.value.match(regExpMedium) && input.value.match(regExpStrong)) no = 3;
                if (no == 1) {
                    weak.classList.add("active");
                    text.style.display = "block";
                    text.textContent = "Your password is too week";
                    text.classList.add("weak");
                    activarDiv(badDiv);
                }
                if (no == 2) {
                    medium.classList.add("active");
                    text.textContent = "Your password is medium";
                    text.classList.add("medium");
                    activarDiv(middleDiv);
                } else {
                    medium.classList.remove("active");
                    text.classList.remove("medium");
                }
                if (no == 3) {
                    weak.classList.add("active");
                    medium.classList.add("active");
                    strong.classList.add("active");
                    text.textContent = "Your password is strong";
                    text.classList.add("strong");
                    activarDiv(goodDiv);
                } else {
                    strong.classList.remove("active");
                    text.classList.remove("strong");
                }
                showBtn.style.display = "block";
                showBtn.onclick = function () {
                    if (input.type == "password") {
                        input.type = "text";
                        showBtn.textContent = "HIDE";
                        showBtn.style.color = "#23ad5c";
                    } else {
                        input.type = "password";
                        showBtn.textContent = "SHOW";
                        showBtn.style.color = "#000";
                    }
                }
            } else {
                indicator.style.display = "none";
                text.style.display = "none";
                showBtn.style.display = "none";
                ocultarDiv();
            }
        }

        function activarDiv(ActiveDiv) {
            if (ActiveDiv.style.display == "grid") {
                return;
            } else {
                //primero, ocultamos todos los divs
                ocultarDiv();
                //después, activamos el que se mandó
                ActiveDiv.style.display = "grid";
            }
        }
        function ocultarDiv() {
            goodDiv.style.display = "none";
            middleDiv.style.display = "none";
            badDiv.style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Probé tu respuesta y todo esta OK, pero solo tengo un detalle y es que al borrar todo lo que contiene el `Input` se sigue mostrando, sabes como evitar que se siga mostrando al borrar todo lo que contiene el `Input` ?

Comment: si se puede, déjame corrijo mi respuesta

Comment: @JohnDoe revísalo de nuevo, ya funciona con ese caso

Comment: Excelente respuesta, clara y concisa